# Comparing huge amounts of binary data quickly

Tags: mysql, database, performance, nosql

I have a database consisting of a large number of images (several million) and content-signatures for those images (generated by [libpuzzle](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle)) which I need to compare.

I've run a bunch of different alternatives to try and make it efficient, including various search algorithms (with [levenshtein difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) currently running fastest) and with various data-points as pre-filters (to cut comparisons down to batches of only a few thousand images) but everything I've tried is still way to slow for production use. I add several thousand images per day, which need to have their signatures compared to everything else in the complete collection.

The two main storage methods I've used are CouchDb and MySql, both required data storage upwards of 10s of gigs and after just a few million records MySql runs far too slowly (even with result-caching and index key-size variations, the indexes are just too big using an approach similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9780314/1358220) which is excellent but still slow), and on Couch it just seems incapable of handling large indexes. I also considered services like Amazon SimpleDB which would solve the storage problem but I expect would be very expensive given the memory requirements for such large indexes and may not fare any better than Couch.

Table structure is simply:

```
ImageId int(11),
Signature VARCHAR(1020) //implemented as text
```

Desired result should be a list of ImageId(s) given an ImageId. A simple self join (ON comparison function) is far too slow.

My implementation is to compare existing images, and on an ongoing basis compare new images with the existing base, to achieve these 2 goals... 1) Identify identical or very-near-identical images (including resizes, crops and minor color variation, and 2) identify similar images to aid image-searches who may be interested in images of a similar visual content. The libpuzzle library provides a score which can be used for both (I use >95% for the former and >80% for the latter).

Essentially my question is, does anyone know of either a
a) a different data storage platform
b) a technique using MySql 
c) or some other (presumably custom) approach
Which can be used to linearly compare huge amounts of binary data, in a very efficient way?

Comment: Does your levenstein function run faster than `squared euclidian distance`?

Comment: you can index on just a prefix of the signature, http://fernandoipar.com/2009/08/12/indexing-text-columns-in-mysql/

Comment: I haven't implemented that, but I would expect so, since my levenshtein approach limits itself to return early once the comparison passes a 'failure boundary' for example if I've computed more than 20% of the difference and found no matches yet it exits as <80% match. (Since I'm only interested in matches with >80% similarity)

Comment: Given modern servers, it should be feasible to hold all the signatures in RAM simultaneously: several million times 1KB equals several gigabytes.  That eliminates the data storage side of the equation, so you're only limited by the speed of your comparison algorithm.  Of course you've still got several *trillion* initial comparisons to make, plus several billion per day, so you're going to need an awful lot of CPU no matter what.

Comment: Can you tell, given an score of a single image, how you are calculating the relative scores to get related images for `1)` and `2)` ? Do you apply some delta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "excellent approach" that you have linked is in fact the answer, but it has one major problem: it shouldn't be done in MySQL, which is terrible for that kind of searches, but in Solr or Sphinx that are built precisely for that.

Since I know Solr here's how you could do it:

Index signatures as text tokenized using ngram filter with constant length (max ngram length = min ngram length) - this will split the signature into "words" (tokens) from the linked answer.

```
<fieldType 
   name="signatureNgrams" 
   stored="false" 
   class="solr.StrField"> 
 <analyzer type="index"> 
   <tokenizer 
       class="solr.analysis.NGramTokenizerFactory" 
       minGramSize="4" 
       maxGramSize="4" 
       /> 
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
 </analyzer> 
</fieldType>
```

Use http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29 to define minimum similarity (how many ngrams have to match).

Comment: Trying out this atm, haven't tried Solr yet (it's way over my head) but the speed of Sphinx is awesome. Not sure yet though if I can get Sphinx to index binary data (or tokenise the the required way too). Will try Solr soon too. Thanks. Hadn't considered using a fulltext engine to do this.

Comment: Just don't use MySQL fulltext search - it's terrible. Solr speed is comparable to Sphinx and even if it isn't enough it supports multiserver setup that will allow you to scale.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was considering writing an NGram plugin for the MySql fulltext indexer to see if it was comparable in speed to the others, but now I won't :)

Comment: Finally got a grip on Solr and it compares token-presence, but not by token-position. (i.e. it matches [ab] in [cdab] the same as in [abcd]). Any chance you know of a solr filter (or something) which would restrict the comparison to be position-dependent?

Comment: Use phrase query and experiment with slop (`qs` query param) to get close, but not exact, matches.

Comment: Any update on this? I am now using libpuzzle to do the same and I am wondering about any good solutions. ~60 million images.