# How to install libpuzzle for PHP on Ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm trying to install libpuzzle PHP extension but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I have tried to follow the following instructions:

> The Puzzle library can also be used through PHP, using a native
>   extension. Prerequisites are the PHP headers, libtool, autoconf and
>   automake. Here are the basic steps in order to install the extension:
>
> (on OpenBSD: export AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.9 ; export
>   AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.61)
>
> cd php/libpuzzle
>
> phpize
>
> ./configure --with-libpuzzle
>
> make clean
>
> make
>
> make install
>
> If libpuzzle is installed in a non-standard location, use: ./configure
>   --with-libpuzzle=/base/directory/for/libpuzzle
>
> Then edit your php.ini file and add:
>
> extension=libpuzzle.so

However when I try to run "./configure --with-libpuzzle" I get the following error:
configure: error: Please reinstall the libpuzzle distribution

Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpuzzle-dev. I would also recommend checking out libpuzzle-php if you are using an apt-get installed php version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you are compiling from source when it is available in the Ubuntu repositories?

```
sudo aptitude install libpuzzle-php
```

Or `apt-get` if you like that instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libpuzzle-php
```

If you somehow did not see it in the repository do a search like this:

```
sudo aptitude search libpuzzle
```

Which on my 12.04 install shows this:

```
p   libpuzzle-bin                 - quick similar image finder - runtime tool                               
p   libpuzzle-bin:i386            - quick similar image finder - runtime tool                               
p   libpuzzle-dev                 - quick similar image finder - development files                          
p   libpuzzle-dev:i386            - quick similar image finder - development files                          
p   libpuzzle-php                 - quick similar image finder - PHP bindings                               
p   libpuzzle-php:i386            - quick similar image finder - PHP bindings                               
p   libpuzzle1                    - quick similar image finder - shared library                             
p   libpuzzle1:i386               - quick similar image finder - shared library
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was available as a repository. The libpuzzle website didn't mention it and my google searches didn't flag anything. I also didn't know you could search apt-get :P

Comment: Yes, it really does. If your thinking of using it for anything there is also a really detailed response to a question about evaluating large numbers of images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703762/libpuzzle-indexing-millions-of-pictures - (The response that got the bounty)